# How to have multiple rows as headers in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid

I have a table of time series data as follows:

```
Period 0 1 2 ...

Start d1 d2 d3...

End e1 e2 e3...

Field1 v2 v2 v3...

and so on.
```

What I want is to do is display the top 3 rows as headers using ag-Grid.

Can someone please help? I already know how to do this "by hand" using html tags but I want to do this using ag-grid. Thanks!

PS: d1,e1 etc are supposed to be dates.

Comment: Is column grouping what you are looking for ? - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping-headers/#column-groups

Comment: Yes, that does it. Thank you!

Comment: Please upvote the comment if it was helpful to you.